# How to encrypt data with AES in Arduino

Tags: encryption, arduino, aes

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt 128 byte of data [using AES128] in an arduino UNO.

```
#include <AESLib.h>

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  uint8_t key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
  char data[] =         "ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF123    4567890ABCDEF12345    67890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF1234567890";//128     byte
  aes128_enc_single(key, data);
  Serial.println(data);
  aes128_dec_single(key, data);
  Serial.println(data);
  delay(15000);
}
```

avr-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-assembler-with-cpp’
This is the error I am getting. Should I update gcc?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/arduino/+bug/1310366